# How to set dynamic value in a useState from parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent component that sends a useState string to its child component.
I can access that useState but I want to set it in another one but I am not able to do that because it rerenders all the time and it breaks the app.

Child component:

```
const Child = ({firstValue}) => {
const [secondValue,setSecondValue) = useState(firstValue);
}
```

First, it takes the default value but it never updates it.
I want to update it automatically when the `firstvalue` changes its value.

I have tried to set it by `setSecondValue(firstValue)` but it runs in a infinite rerender loop and it breaks.

I also tried with: `const [secondValue,setSecondValue) = useState(...secondValue, {value: firstValue});`

Also it is worth to mention that I need it to be updated onload, not in any onClick or onChange function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need to use `useEffect` to update `secondValue` when `firstValue` changes

```
useEffect(() => {setSecondValue(firstValue)}, [firstValue])
```